# I am trying to create a language a^n b^n-1 c^n-2 using DCG but can't make the succ(0) to handle n

Tags: prolog, dcg, successor-arithmetics

```
s(Count) --> a(Count), b(Count), c(Count).

a(0) --> [].
a(succ(Count)) --> [a], a(Count).

b(0) --> [].
b(succ(succ(Count))) --> [b], b(Count).

c(0) --> [].
c(succ(succ(succ(Count)))) --> [c], c(Count).
```

Well it is easy to create a language like a^n b^n c^n using succ(0) for every rule but when it comes to vary the n for each block of a b and c's It is not working.

Comment: Of interest: Noncontracting grammar [Transforming into context-sensitive grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncontracting_grammar#Transforming_into_context-sensitive_grammar)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your clauses, like:

```
c(0) --> [].
c(succ(succ(succ(Count)))) --> [c], c(Count).
```

Note that you only match two cases - zero or three characters, but what about one or two? Modifying `c` to account for every acceptable length seems like a dead end though, much easier to specify how many `c`s you want relative to your number of `a`s and `b`s at the place where you control them all, that is in `s`:

```
s(succ(succ(Count))) --> a(succ(succ(Count))), b(succ(Count)), c(Count).
```

This naturally translates to your specification: For `N` of at least two, accept `N` `a`s, `N-1` `b`s and `N-2` `c`s.

Now the rest falls into place easily:

```
a(0) --> [].
a(succ(Count)) --> [a], a(Count).

b(0) --> [].
b(succ(Count)) --> [b], b(Count).

c(0) --> [].
c(succ(Count)) --> [c], c(Count).
```

Of course, you can replace them with a generic clause `char(Char, Count)` (left as an exercise).

```
?- phrase(s(succ(succ(succ(0)))), X).
X = [a, a, a, b, b, c].
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer by @firefrorefiddle I'd like note a three things. Firstly, when using Peano numbers, it is more customary to use the functor s/1 to denote the successor and a single letter like X for the variable, thus obtaining smaller terms:

```
s(X)            succ(Count)
s(s(X))         succ(succ(Count))
s(s(s(X)))      succ(succ(succ(Count)))
s(s(s(s(X))))   succ(succ(succ(succ(Count))))
.               .
.               .
.               .
```

Secondly, to further improve readability, it would then be favourable to choose a different name for the DCG, maybe something like language//1 instead of s//1. And thirdly, instead of writing the same DCG-rules for `a`, `b` and `c`, you could define a more general DCG that lets you specify an element and its number of occurrence in the list. Putting all this together, you DCG might look something like this:

```
language(s(s(X))) -->
   element_frequency(a,s(s(X))),
   element_frequency(b,s(X)),
   element_frequency(c,X).

element_frequency(_E,0) -->
   [].
element_frequency(E,s(X)) -->
   [E],
   element_frequency(E,X).
```

In the above code language//1 corresponds to s//1 in your code and element_frequency//2 is the replacement for a//1, b//1 and c//1. If you query this DCG you'll find that it still produces the same answers as the one in @firefrorefiddle's post, e.g.:

```
   ?- phrase(language(s(s(s(0)))),L).
L = [a,a,a,b,b,c]
```

Answer (score -2):

[] of DCG is match any time.
Let's up side down the a,b,c rules.

```
s(Count) --> a(Count), b(Count), c(Count).

a(succ(Count)) --> [a], a(Count).
a(0) --> [].

b(succ(succ(Count))) --> [b], b(Count).
b(0) --> [].

c(succ(succ(succ(Count)))) --> [c], c(Count).
c(0) --> [].

:- s(N,[a,a,a,a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c],[]),writeln(N).
:- halt.
```